# Weird behavior when coping a list of string arrays to excel file

Tags: c#, list, winforms, excel-interop

I have an application that creates a string array from some values collected over CAN network. I add the string array to a listview and then add it to a list property which is sent to a method to copy the list to an excel file.

I add the array to listview using this:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(UnitsCheckedArray);
DCSDlv.Items.Add(item);
```

Right after that I add the same array to a list of string[] using this:

```
UnitsChecked.Add(UnitsCheckedArray);
```

This is the result when adding string array to the listview
[image]

I write the data in the UnitsChecked list by calling a write to excel method:

```
public void WriteToExcel(List<String[]> list)
    {

        int Row = GetFirstEmptyRow();
        int Column = 1;
        foreach(var item in list)
        {
            Column = 1;

            foreach(var subItem in item)
            {
                excelWS.Cells[Row, Column] = subItem;
                Column++;
            }

            Row++;
        }
```

Below is what gets printed to the excel file. As can see the data does not match what is in the listview.
[image]

I am at a loss as to why the data is changing in the list. The only time data is written to the UnitsChecked list is with the code listed above. There is no other code that touches that list. Also the data is written to the listview and to the list at the same time so the same data should be in both.

This is where the list is touched in my code:
[image]

***ADDED DETAILS***
Code ran at BGWorker completed. This is where data is sent to the listview and the list used to create excel data.

```
 private void bg1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(UnitsCheckedArray);
        DCSDlv.Items.Add(item);
        DCSDlv.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.ColumnContent);

        UnitsChecked.Add(UnitsCheckedArray);
        UpdateStatusMessage("Record Added Successfully");
        btStartTest.Enabled = true;
        GenReportButton.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Comment: @PhilippeB. The data in the excel screenshot is the same on every row. In the source data, the rows have different data.

Comment: It looks like your `List<String[]> list` only contains the last Item in the ListView. Show the code that fills the List you're passing to the `WriteToExcel()` method.

Comment: The data is different. Look at the last two numbers in the serial number of eachrow. In the listview  the last two numbers of the serial goes 10, 20 , 30 , 40 , 50, 10 , 20, 30 , 40 ,50. In the excel file all rows end in 50 for the serial number. Also for the SW part numbers and HW part numbers in the list view some end with 66AA and some end in 63AA. In the excel document they all end in   66AA.

Comment: @Jimi: The listview and the list are both filled at the same exact time on a backgroundworker completed task. So at the point where data is added to the listview and added to the list is the same. The data is added via a variable called UnitsCheckedArray shown above. I have added above what is ran at BG worker completed. As you will see both list and listview should have same data unless I am missing something. Which is possible and why I posted my question.

Comment: You haven't added the code that modifies `UnitsCheckedArray`. Could you please share that?

Comment: My psychic powers are telling me that there is an "accessing modified closure" defect somewhere in this program, but my psychic powers are often wrong.

Comment: You have described, twice, that *I write the data in the UnitsChecked list by calling a write to excel method*, but you're not. In the `WriteToExcel()` method you don't write to that list, you use that list to write to `excelWS.Cells`. What happens in between is unknown. Note that `ListViewItem` is a reference object, see that you don't use the same reference (the last one you added) all the time. The *closure effect* that Eric Lippert is mentioning shouldn't happen here, but change `Column++` in `Column += 1` etc.

Comment: There's another thing related to BackGroudWorker: you don't use the `e.Result` object to set your ListView/List, you use an unknown object, probably set in the UI Thread and modified by the BGW in the DoWork event without passing it in using the `RunWorkerAsync(object)` overload and passing it out in the `e.Result` object.

Comment: I understand what you guys are asking for how I populate the UnitsCheckedArray. I just have a question first. If data is written to the listview and the list of string[] at the same time then why would how I populate UnitsCheckedArray matter. Some more info is that the backgroundworker tasks cant change data in the array until the BG worker completed task finishes.  This is how the process goes btnTest button is pressed which starts the process of populating the array -> button is disable while bgworker is running-> array is populated -> array is copied to listview and list -> button enabled

Comment: At Jimi you are correct I am not describing what I mean very well. What I should say is I write data in the UnitsChecked list to the excel file by passing the UnitsChecked list to the WriteToExcel() Method.

Comment: @Jimi again: You are correct I am updating the UnitsCheckedArray that was created in the UI thread from the bgworker using a delegate (Im sure there is a better way to do this but my knowledge is limited). But since listview is populated at the same time as the string[] list is populated from the same variable than why would what happens in the bgworker matter. I am not challenging I am asking.

Comment: *I am not challenging I am asking*. Of course, nobody is thinking that: you have a problem, we're trying to solve it; asking for details is part of it. The BackGroundWorker *thing* is just a symptom that not everything is as described and not everything is processed as it should. I understand that you have to extract pieces of code to show what you're doing an much of it is missing, so you're probably not showing the piece of code that causes the problem because you still don't know what that is.

Comment: You have to debug your code: at some point, the list that creates the Excel output is filled with the same data for some reason. Follow that List/array (add a watch, use the Find tool and add breakpoints, whatever) and you'll find out what happened. You could also *experiment* a different approach: get the data directly from the ListView.Items collection instead of using that secondary List.

Comment: @jimi: Yes I planned on debugging tomorrow when I get to work. I just was hoping that someone would know what was going on with the limited data I have posted.

Comment: You are not adding the array to the `Listview`; you are creating a new `ListViewItem` each time based on the contents of the array and adding that item to the `Listview`. A string array is a reference type.  Unless you recreate `UnitsCheckedArray` each time, each entry in `UnitsChecked` (the List) will be a reference to the same array and hold the last values assigned to that array; that is why the Excel file contains multiple copies of the last row in the `ListView`.

Comment: @ TnTinMn: So if I understand you correctly I am not actually saving real data to my list of String[](UnitsChecked) I am actually only adding multiple references to the UnitsCheckedArray. So when the Excel file is being created it just looks at the current values in the UnitsCheckedArray at each loop through the foreach statement. That makes sense if I understand you correctly.

Comment: @pleslie you are right sorry for that